# Does it matter if I market good-keyword.com or companyname.com?

Tags: seo, domains, marketing

Let's say I offer a service that I call "Small business booster”. I have purchased the equivalent of smallbusinessbooster.com (and a bunch of synonyms and misspellings). I have also managed to purchase the equivalent of cheap-marketing.com (but not cheapmarketing.com, which in this case is just an ad site and not a quality content site belonging to a competitor). I'm thinking I should set up cheap-marketing.com to point to smallbusinessbooster.com/cheap-marketing.

Does it matter if I use smallbusinessbooster.com or cheap-marketing.com in ads? I'm thinking it may be better for SEO to use cheap-marketing.com and maybe also for humans since ”smallbusinessbooster” might be less easy to read and remember correctly. Drawback being of course that some would end up att cheapmarketing.com instead...

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive me. People really have the wrong impression of SEO and IM (Internet Marketing). It really is not that complicated and doing a bunch of odd gyrations really does not help. It also does not help that so many so-called SEO experts put crazy ideas into peoples minds. Do not listen to the "me too" chatter. SEO and IM are really simple processes when you get down to it.

Do not divide your work over two or more domains. You are dividing your potential. Pick a domain, preferably your company name or a simple and easy to remember domain that will be "top of mind" (marketing speak) for your customers. Do not be the sleazy car salesman. Do honest work on one domain and represent yourself well and give good value to customers. It will work.

Forget the misspellings. For get the ad domain.

Either chose to use your company name or an easy domain name that people can remember that ties in with what you do. That is IM 101.

Again, it frustrates me to no end what the online SEO folks are doing. I see it here nearly every day. SEO is simple. Really. I will get off my soap-box now.

Comment: really helpful, you're telling it like it is :)

Comment: @ThatGuy343 I hate to be mean and I hope that I wasn't too harsh. We get these SEO questions all the time and some of them are really far afield. There are too many SEO experts out there many of them parroting junk de' jure all in an effort to make a buck or to carve out a bit of space for themselves. There are real experts of course. But the fact of the matter is, SEO is really not a complicated process. Follow some simple steps and play around a bit to get your head around how your site needs to compete and your done. Really.

Comment: @closetnoc  I appreciate your advice (and I don't take offence of course). Your suggestions as I percieve them are: "don't divide content over multiple domains", and "chose to use your company name or an easy domain name that people can remember".

Comment: @maratonic You got it! Also, keep it simple. Create compelling and unique content that people will want to link to, go above and beyond on some topics and become a resource/reference. Do not fall for the SEO tricks. There is no magic set of buttons and levers that will make your site perform except one- a creating a damn good site. When you are ready, and if you need it, I can help with a simple/minimal SEO strategy that is really a get back to basics strategy without the crazy bull that actually works extremely well. I found that much of the SEO advice is junk and actually a waste of time.